# WakefulIntentService cannot instantiate listener

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

I found that I have to specify listener in an xml file, such as:

```
<WakefulIntentService listener="pathhere.MainListener" />
```

The problem with that is I cannot add more than one listener, so I have to use this sort of workaround:

```
    public MainListener(ListenerTable listenerType) {
        this.listenerType = listenerType;
        System.out.println("Listener Type is " + listenerType);
    }

    public void scheduleAlarms(AlarmManager mgr, PendingIntent pi, Context ctxt) {
        System.out.println("Scheduling Alarm");
        if (listenerType == ListenerTable.CELL) {
            System.out.println("In scheduling cell");
            mgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                    SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 60000,
                    AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES / (15 * 60) * 10, pi);
        } else if (listenerType == ListenerTable.WIFI) {
            mgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                    SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 60000,
                    AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES / (15 * 60) * 60, pi);
        }

    }

    public void sendWakefulWork(Context ctxt) {

        switch (listenerType) {
        case CELL:
            WakefulIntentService.sendWakefulWork(ctxt, CellService.class);
            break;
        case WIFI:
            WakefulIntentService.sendWakefulWork(ctxt, WifiService.class);
            break;
        default:
            //Do nothing
            break;
        }
    }
```

And I pass the schedule alarm in my main activity as:

```
WakefulIntentService.scheduleAlarms(new MainListener(ListenerTable.CELL),this, false);
```

Now the problem is I am getting a run time error which starts with:

```
01-26 21:49:12.615: E/AndroidRuntime(8064): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.commonsware.cwac.wakeful.AlarmReceiver: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not create instance of listener
```

I guess the reason is because it uses the xml file above and doesn't pass any methods to constructor. Since `WakefulIntentService` doesn't support multiple listeners, how can I simply manage multiple alarms within `WakefulIntentService`?

Answer (score 0):

> Since WakefulIntentService doesn't support multiple listeners, how can I simply manage multiple alarms within WakefulIntentService?

First, read [the `README` section on asking questions](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful#questions), so you get the right tags on your StackOverflow question in the future.

Then, follow [the "Basic Usage" instructions](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful#basic-usage). My helper code for `AlarmManager` is designed for fairly simple scenarios, but you do not need to use that code.

Comment: Thanks for responding but without adding the listener to xml file, it doesn't work. I couldn't find the exact part that says the other way of doing it.

Comment: At the basic usage, it says "Next, create a class implementing the WakefulIntentService.AlarmListener interface. This class needs to have a no-argument public constructor in addition to the interface method implementations" So I cannot really use it for my case.
And my question is, because I cannot use in my case, what else should I be using?

Comment: @SarpKaya: "At the basic usage, it says" -- no, it does not. That is under the "Alarm Usage" heading. I pointed you, in words and via hyperlink, to the "Basic Usage" heading.